# Run time error 1004 method "ontime" of object failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have following VBA code to refresh all sheets on specific interval

```
Public interval As Double

Sub macro_timer()

interval = Now + TimeValue("00:50:00")

End Sub

Sub my_macro()

 End Sub

 Sub stop_macro()
 Application.OnTime earliesttime:=interval, procedure:="my_macro",schedule:=False

  End Sub
```

When I try to run stop_macro it throws run time error.

Comment: Refresh from what? Dont they refresh themselves?

Comment: Refresh because I have imported data through external web data

Comment: You missing a comma in your `OnTime` method > `...Procedure:="my_macro", Schedule:=False`. This code should not compile.

Comment: Using a VBA timer has all kinds of issues to deal with. You are much better off using vb.net (which you have tagged in addition to vba for some reason) and creating a stand-alone app using COM for Excel.

Comment: I have comma in my actual code In question by mistake it was deleted sorry for the same

Comment: Well, where do you start your `OnTime` procedure? Right now, your error will occur because you try to clear a previously set procedure with `schedule:=False`. If this is not present the code will return error 1004

Comment: I got your point, thx @JvdV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of VBA weirdness, if the previous scheduled procedure is not there, it will fail.  Change the last parameter to **True**.

```
Sub my_macro()

    MsgBox "Hello World"

End Sub

Sub stop_macro()

     interval = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")

     Application.OnTime interval, "my_macro",, True

End Sub
```